# Context of "when?"

Tags: expressions, meaning-in-context

One example comes from this song in "the Music Man."

> Gary, Indiana, Gary, Indiana 
>   Gary, Indiana, let me say it once again 
>   Gary, Indiana, Gary, Indiana 
>   Gary, Indiana, that's the town that knew me WHEN.

Another example comes from a friend who met Taylor Swift at age 13, before she became famous, and therefore knew her "when."

The meaning of "when" is something like, before one became established or famous.

But what is the context/appropriate expression of it? Is it something like "when I was young..."?

(On the other hand, if someone is young AND famous, then it's no longer "when.")

Comment: "When" can be completely contextual...when someone was young, when someone was single, when someone was a starving artist.  You'd really need to understand the context to which "when" refers.  As for if someone is young and famous, when could be before they were famous (but obviously, still young).

Comment: It's just a cut-down version of what's more commonly expressed as [***way back when***](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/way_back_when) *- a time in the distant past.*

Comment: @fumbleFingers: Yes, "way back when" or "long, long ago."

Comment: @Tom: Not sure if it's more a BrE thing, but I'm more likely to speak of [*back in the day*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/back-in-the-day) (which as Cambridge says there, is more associated with *positive* connotations). To me, *[way back] when* is effectively "neutral", but since I've hardly ever heard it without *way back*, maybe I'm just a bit out of touch with how the one-word version is now being used.

Comment: "When" used in this way is, I believe, entirely AmE.

Comment: @ColinFine: That doesn't surprise me, but that's good to know. That would explain the notion of "upward mobility," which is more ingrained in the American psyche than elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"I knew [him/her] when" is an idiom in English. It is not about the speaker's age (*I knew her when I was young* is not an idiom.) It is more about a defining event or series of events in the life (no matter how young) of the person about whom you are speaking. One [dictionary](http://www.yourdictionary.com/when) defines it as

> At an earlier and less prosperous time. "He's mister high and mighty now, but *I remember him when*."

On May 22, 2007, a video of a young boy and his younger brother was uploaded to YouTube. The young boy (Harry Davies-Carr) is holding his little brother [Charlie](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_OBlgSz8sSM&feature=kp) on his lap. Harry explains that Charlie bit him, and puts his finger in Charlie's mouth to demonstrate. Charlie bites him again, to no one's surprise. Only this time it *hurts!*

The video went viral, and has been seen over 720 *million* times. Harry and Charlie became minor celebrities. Though Harry was a young child when the video was uploaded, anyone who knew Harry and Charlie before the video went viral can rightfully claim:

> I knew Harry and Charlie *when*!

<sup>The video is really cute. If you haven't seen it, do watch it.</sup>

Comment: I don't think *[way back] when* has any significant overtones of "less prosperous". It's probably just as likely to be used of earlier times when the speaker was younger and more vigorous, with *positive* connotations.

Comment: Perhaps. *I knew him when* is not commonly used of an unknown poverty-striken person who used to be famous and wealthy. Lots of people knew him *then*. *I knew him when* implies a time when relatively few people knew him.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Yes, "way back when" works. But there is an element of "way back when..." things weren't so good as today.

Comment: Well yes, but that's surely because of one likely context where you might say you *knew* someone a long time ago. But a bunch of people eking out their twilight years in a run-down nursing home might just as easily reminisce about how good their earlier lives were, *way back when [they were young, wealthy, and in good health]*. I think your interpretation of the connotations is more a reflection of your *personal* attitude to the past than anything inherent in the idiom itself.

Comment: Agreed, but *I knew him when* is not typically used in those situations, whereas *way back when* is often used that way. However, OP asked about "I knew him *when*", not "When would you use *way back when*?" ')